# Short satiric/dystopic story: "boot up" dialog while restoring a brain dump to virtual space - music copyright agent

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall fairly recently seeing a short story that was the "boot up dialog" while a stored "brain dump" was being first revived into a virtual computational state: being "uploaded". During the process, their memories were being scanned for copyrighted music (and other things?), and, since the person was not wealthy, had to choose between ads, and having parts of memories removed/overwritten.

Anyone know the source? My searchfu has failed me on this one.

Comment: This was in a recent "Best of" anthology with a name like "Life 2.0" but I haven't found the right one yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this as a short video form, *Welcome to Life*, by Tom Scott. You can watch it on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFe9wiDfb0E).

Comment: Clearly, I either read a transcript of this, or just remembered it wrong. This is exactly the work I had in mind. Thanks!